# How to use C-j C-k to move window in term mode using evil?

Tags: key-bindings, evil, window

The bindings of `C-j` `C-k` to `evil-window-down[up]` work well every where apart form term mode. term mode rebinds these to `C-w j` `C-w k` - this is super annoying!
How can i make term use the `C-j/C-k` bindings I use every where else?

At the moment i'm doing this:

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-h") 'evil-window-left)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-j") 'evil-window-down)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-k") 'evil-window-up)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-l") 'evil-window-right)

(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-h") 'evil-window-left)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-j") 'evil-window-down)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-k") 'evil-window-up)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-l") 'evil-window-right)

(define-key global-map (kbd "C-h") #'evil-window-left)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-j") #'evil-window-down)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-k") #'evil-window-up)
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-l") #'evil-window-right)
```

But term and Python Inferior REPL processes override them.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i updated the question with what i tried so far

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when I am using `org mode`. 
The following code solves it. 
Note that you need the following package: 
[noctuid/general.el: More convenient key definitions in emacs](https://github.com/noctuid/general.el)

```
  (general-override-mode)

  (general-def 'normal 'override
    "C-h" 'evil-window-left
    "C-j" 'evil-window-down
    "C-k" 'evil-window-up
    "C-l" 'evil-window-right
    )
```

Reference: https://github.com/noctuid/evil-guide#user-content-preventing-certain-keys-from-being-overridden